# Convert String to bytes, and back again

Tags: java, string, byte

I have a string `cityName` which I decoded into bytes as follows:

`byte[] cityBytes = cityName.getBytes("UTF-8");`

...and stored the bytes somewhere. When I retrieve those bytes, how can I decode them back into a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`String(byte[], Charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) or [`String(byte[], String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor.

```
byte[] rawBytes = /* whatevs */

try
{
    String decoded = new String(rawBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    // or
    String decoded = new String(rawBytes, "UTF-8");
    // best, if you're using Java 7 (thanks to @ColinD):
    String decoded = new String(rawBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
{
    // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6030187/139010
    throw new AssertionError("UTF-8 not supported");
}
```

Comment: you don't need to use `Charset.forName("UTF-8");` Just using "UTF-8" works normally.

Comment: Just saying, using a plain `String` looks nicer. But its up to you.

Comment: @Jon - the `Charset` constructor has the advantage that it does not throw an `UnsupportedEncodingException`. This will never be thrown for UTF-8 as it is mandatory for all JVMs to support this encoding.

Comment: @Jon more specifically, `Charset#forName()` only throws _unchecked_ exceptions.

Comment: In Java 7 you can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` too.

Comment: @ColinD I did not know that (not yet using 7 @ work). ***Thank you.***

Answer (score 0):

The [String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has a few constructors that accept an array of bytes, including [one that takes an array of bytes and a String representation of a charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) and [another that takes a Charset object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29). There are also constructors that take the offset and length of the String as arguments, if the String is only a small section of the byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
String cityName = new String(cityByte,"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

`String s = new String(cityByte, "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

```
String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)
```