# How to implement rawurldecode in Java?

Tags: java, android, web-applications

I'd like to convert PHP code to Java, that is to decode a string stored as an encoded URI format.

That is, change

> This%20is%20a%20%2Burl%2B%21

into

> This is a +url+!

I've looked at java.net.URI, but there are no suitable examples, and it seems that anything to be decoded by it needs to be in a proper URI format. I'd like to convert a string that isn't in proper format, but contains HTML encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode("This%20is%20a%20%2Burl%2B%21", "UTF-8");
```

UTF-8 is of course just an example. Use whatever your input encoding is.

Comment: I get an UnsupportedEncodingException error when trying to use UTF-8. Any suggestions on how to fix this or did I just miss out something obvious?

Comment: I don't get an UnsupportedEncodingException. What JVM do you use?

Comment: Uh, not quite sure, still very new to Java. Using Eclipse, didn't alter default installation settings. How do I check?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a typo? Can you post your code? The people here are pretty convinced this should not happen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030059/url-decoding-unsupportedencodingexception-in-java

Comment: Oh, ok, got it. I didn't know you were supposed to put it in a try-catch, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use URLDecoder ([doc here)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html). It just decodes an x-www-form-urlencoded String.

```
    String decodedString = URLDecoder.decode("This%20is%20a%20%2Burl%2B%21");
    System.out.println(decodedString);
```

Comment: you can use the solution Joe23 gave you, but therefore you have to know how the text is encoded (utf8, ...) - or just use this and don't mind the deprecated for now :)