# Why is UnsupportedEncodingException not a subclass of RuntimeException?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

I've come across the `UnsupportedEncodingException` while using the `URLEncoder` with the UTF-8 encoding and it forces me to write my code like this:

```java
String foo = ... // contains unsafe characters
try {
    foo = URLEncoder.encode(foo, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    // do something with the exception that should never occur
}
```

Instead of just this:

```java
String foo = ... // contains unsafe characters
foo = URLEncoder.encode(foo, "UTF-8");
```

The [documentation of `URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) discourages the use of any encoding other than UTF-8:

> Note: The World Wide Web Consortium Recommendation states that UTF-8 should be used. Not doing so may introduce incompatibilities.

And the UTF-8 encoding should always be available, at least according to the [Supported Encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) page from the documentation.

The accepted answer to the question on [how to handle the `UnsupportedEncodingException`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6030059/) and if it can even occur is "It cannot happen, unless there is something fundamentally broken in your JVM".

So I'm wondering, why does the UnsupportedEncodingException class not extend the RuntimeException class, which would allow me to use the second code snippet? Is it just because it exists as it is right now and it would be hard to change that?

Comment: What exactly is your reasoning why it should be a `RuntimeException`? "I don't want to have to catch it" is not the strongest argument.

Comment: My reasoning is that I don't want to have to catch an exception that never occurs. @daniu

Comment: You can hide that ugliness in one place in one of your own methods.

Comment: I would do that if I had to use this multiple times, which I, fortunately, don't have to. It still bugs me to see this. @Henry

Comment: Well, it is as it is. You have to deal with it.

Comment: What would be the negatives of making it a subclass of RuntimeException in a future version of java? It's been like this since JDK1.1

Comment: It would potentially break existing code.

Comment: Could you give me an example of code that would break with that change? That would answer my question, because currently I just can't think of anything that would break.

Comment: Use a CharSet constant. Those do not throw.

Comment: As of Java 10, there is a [URLEncoder.encode method that takes a Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,java.nio.charset.Charset)) which will not throw the exception, since obviously the Charset is valid already.  So you can write `URLEncoder.encode(foo, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` and there is no need for a try/catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this was changed some existing code could be broken. For example

```
try {
    ... do something that could throw UnsupportedEncodingException
} catch (IOException e) {
    ... handle the exception
}
```

If `UnsupportedEncodingException` is no longer an `IOException` it would not be handled any more.